# Hibernate OneToMany - Child entity is not getting persisted despite specifying the relationship correctly

Tags: hibernate, liquibase, dropwizard

I have a main entity:

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIN_ENTITY")
public class MainEntity {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID", length = 32, updatable = 
  false)
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
  private String id;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false,
        length = 36, updatable = false)
  private String userId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "mainEntity")
  @Builder.Default
  private Set<ChildEntity> childList = new HashSet<>();

  public void addChildToList(final ChildEntity child) {
    child.setMainEntity(this);
    childList.setUserId(this.getUserId());
    this.childList.add(child);
  }

}
```

And I have a child entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD_ENTITY")
public class ChildEntity {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", length = 32, updatable = 
   false)
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
   @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
   private String id;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false,
        length = 36, updatable = false)
   private String userId;

   @Column(name = "SUBJECT_TYPE", length = 20)
   private String subjectType;

   @Column(name = "SUBJECT_ID", length = 36)
   private String subjectId;

   @Column(name = "CUSTOM_ID", 32)
   private String customId;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumns(
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "MAINENTT_MNENT_FK"),
        value =
                {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_ENTITY_ID",
                                referencedColumnName = "ID"),
                        @JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_ENTITY_USER_ID",
                                referencedColumnName = "USER_ID")
                })
private MainEntity mainEntity;

}
```

Now, when I create `mainEntity` an instance of MainEntity and use the function `addChildToList` and pass an instance of the child entity

```
mainEntity.addChildToList(
                    ChildEntity
                            .builder()
                            .customId("123")
                            .subjectType("user")
                            .subjectId("456)
                            .build())
```

I see that the child entity is not getting persisted in the child table at all. The child table remains empty. I enabled Hibernate debug logs, and I do not see the insert statement for the child table at all.

I spent two days looking into this and explored similar questions on Stack overflow, but in vain.

Would be grateful in getting any hints or pointers as to what I am missing.
I am using Dropwizard framework btw.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was not specifying `cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true` on the `childList` attribute on the parent entity. For some reason, I was thinking that in my use case, the child entity can outlive the parent entity, but I was wrong. Now I'm able to see that the child entity is getting persisted.